# ValueError at /author/admin/ in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, urlconf

I have the following blog project :

**urls.py** conf :

```
  url(r'^author/(?P<author>\w+)/$', views.getAllPosts, name='grabAuthorPosts')
```

**posts/models**:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=500, default = True)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    category = models.ManyToManyField('Category')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def slug(self):
        return slugify(self.title)
```

**posts/views**:

```
def getAllPosts(request, author=False):
    latest_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
    comments = Comment.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
    author_posts = User.objects.get(id=author)
    author_posts = author_posts.post_set.all()

    context = {
        'latest_posts':latest_posts,
        'comments':comments,
        'author_posts':author_posts
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/getAllPosts.html', context)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**templates/posts/getAllPosts**:

```
<a href={% url 'grabAuthorPosts' author=post.author.username %}>
{{post.author}}</a>
```

I am trying to make it so that when the `post.author` link is clicked, the user will be taken to a page consisting of posts related to that particular author. The link formulation itself seems ok, as when clicked on a post created by admin, the url reads `localhost/author/admin/`

I believe my problem is in getting the context variable `author_posts` to work. I'm new to Django so any explanation greatly appreciated.

`latest_posts`, as well as `author=False` is used elsewhere in the template to get all posts regardless of author, which works fine.

The error is :

```
ValueError at /author/admin/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'admin'
```

Comment: Modify the view! You cannot filter by a foreign key, you should you the select_related method for that. Instead you could query for the given author <Id> And formulate the query like this: `author = Author.objects.get(id=Id); author.post_set.all()`

Comment: Thanks - Edited answer - ive removed filter on foreign key and adjusted query as per the above, albeit there is no Author model, it's djangos User model which is linked to my extended Profile model. Still getting same error

Comment: Hey David, it is not working because the implementation I've suggested to you needs the User id instead of the name (which should be more correct anyway).
Thus you need to change `<a href={% url 'grabAuthorPosts'  author=post.author.username %}>` with `<a href={% url 'grabAuthorPosts'  author=post.author.id %}>`
And then as Bear suggested you should change the url